# How to find the average distance from a point to a all the points on a given segment?

Tags: calculus, geometry

Suppose point $C$ is directly above point $B$ of $\overline{AB}$. $|\overline{AB}| =2$, and the distance from $C$ to $B$ is $1$.

How can I find the average distance from point $C$ to every point on $\overline{AB}$?
[image]

To further clarify my question, suppose we start to randomly pick ten points $A,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,B$ on $\overline{AB}$ and connect them all to point $C$.

[image]

The average distance from point $C$ to points $A,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,B$ would then be $$\frac{|\overline{CA}|+|\overline{CD}|+|\overline{CE}|+|\overline{CF}|+|\overline{CG}|+|\overline{CH}|+|\overline{CI}|+|\overline{CJ}|+|\overline{CK}|+|\overline{CB}|}{10}$$
Ideally, there should be infinitly many segments, but I cannot draw them all.

Now, return to my question: what is the the average distance from point $C$ to every point on $\overline{AB}$?

I think this question is related to [Triangle Line Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleLinePicking.html), but I have not been able to figure out the set up for solving this problem. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: This is what integrals are for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is $\frac12\int_0^2 \sqrt{x^2+1}\;dx$, as Aditya Dua explains. To evaluate this integral, make the substitution $x=\sinh u$, so that $x^2+1=\cosh^2u$ and $dx=\cosh u\;du$. We get

$$\begin{align}
\frac12\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}2}\cosh^2 u\;du&=\frac14\int_0^{\sinh^{-1}2}(\cosh 2u+1)\;du\\
&=\frac14\left[\frac12\sinh 2u+u\right]_0^{\sinh^{-1}2}\\
&=\frac14\left[\sinh u\cosh u+u\right]_0^{\sinh^{-1}2}\\
&=\frac14(2\sqrt{2^2+1}+\sinh^{-1}2)\\
&=\frac12\sqrt 5+\frac14\sinh^{-1}2
\end{align}$$

which is about $1.47894285754460$. You can find the various hyperbolic identities at [this link](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/Engineering%20maths%20first%20aid%20kit/latexsource%20and%20diagrams/3_6.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Without loss of generality, let the coordinates of A, B, C be: $(0, 0), (b, 0)$, and $(b, c)$. An arbitrary point on AB is described by the coordinates $(x, 0)$, where $x \in [0, b]$. The distance from C to this point is given by $d(x) = \sqrt{(b-x)^2 + c^2}$. Now you can integrate $d(x)$ w.r.t. to $x$ to get the average distance $\bar{d}$.

$\bar{d} = \frac{1}{b}\int_0^{b} \sqrt{(b-x)^2 + c^2} dx$.

I think a substitution like $(b-x) = c \tan \theta$ might work.

Specifically, in your example, $b=2$ and $c=1$.

Comment: To get the average distance, you have to divide that integral by $b$.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you. I have edited my answer.